# Cannot declare field 'pair' to be of abstract type 'System'

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual, abstract, pure-virtual

My `SystemManager` has a map of `System` classes, where each system is mapped to type `systype`

```
typedef string systype;
```

In the header file, this `map` is declared:

```
class SystemManager
{
    public:
        SystemManager();
        ~SystemManager();

        map<systype, System> systems;

        System* getSystemPointer(systype);
};
```

And I try to add a `DrawSystem` (a class derived from `System`) to my "systems map" in the constructor:

```
SystemManager::SystemManager()
{
    systems["Draw"] = DrawSystem();
}
```

This gives me the error:

> cannot declare filed '`pair<systype, System>::second`' to be of abstract type System

I can't figure out what is causing it.

Here are my `System` and `DrawSystem` classes in case that matters:

```
class System
{
    public:
        System();

        systype type;
        vector<cptype> args;
        virtual void update(vector<Cp*>) = 0; //= 0 is for pure virtual function
};

class DrawSystem : public System
{
    friend class Game; //allows to draw on render window
    public:
        DrawSystem();

        void update(vector<Cp*>);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store `System`s by value (`map<systype, System> systems;`) in the following line:

```
systems["Draw"] = DrawSystem();
```

[slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) occurs and you're actually trying to create an instance of `System`, which is abstract.

The simplest fix here is to switch to pointers instead:

```
map<systype, System*> systems;
```

but consider also using something like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead, to avoid manual memory management. E.g.:

```
map<systype, unique_ptr<System>> systems; //pre C++11: put an extra space between >>
```

and:

```
systems["Draw"] = unique_ptr<DrawSystem>(new DrawSystem());
```

or even better - not using `new` (as suggested in the comments by [sjdowling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558027/sjdowling)):

```
systems["Draw"] = std::make_unique<DrawSystem>();
```

Comment: One can add that `std::make_unique` is available only with standard C++14

Answer (score 0):

***System*** is abstact class, because he has pure virtual function. You cannot create an instance of System.
Try to do following

```
map<systype, System*> systems;
...
systems["Draw"] = new DrawSystem();
...
~SystemManager()
{
    // call delete for each item in systems
}
```